# SSH key lost in tunnel

Tags: networking, ssh, nat

I'm trying to connect to my private VPC instance through a NAT instance with tunnelling

i'm defining -A to make the NAT instance an agent for my key and -i for the key file.
When trying

```
ssh -A -i 'path_to_key' ec2-user@net.instance.ip
```

it works and connect to my NAT, but trying to tunnel to my private instance it always fail because of key problem

```
   ssh -A -i 'path_to_key' ec2-user@net.instance.ip ssh -t -t ubuntu@private_instance_ip
```

I supposed it does not pass my key from the NAT to the private instance.

When doing `ssh-add path_to_key` and then running the same command excluding the -i part - it works as well.

How can I make my NAT pass the key in the -i parameter to the private instance?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `ssh -A` option only works with the keys you've already loaded into the agent, which `-i` *doesn't* do automatically. In other words, you must have a ssh-agent, and `ssh-add` the key.

```
ssh-add 'path_to_key'
```

---

As a side note, you're using `-t` in the wrong place – your inner connection will have a tty but won't know the correct parameters (such as window size). The option is more important for *outer* connection (that is, `ssh -t server1 ssh server2`), then it becomes unnecessary for the inner one.

---

There's another way to make a two-hop connection. Instead of running ssh on the proxy, you could run it locally using SSH's TCP-forwarding feature:

```
ssh -i 'path' -o ProxyCommand="ssh -W %H:%P ec2-user@net.instance" ubuntu@private_instance
```

This does not need `-A` or an agent at all, as your client connects directly to the private instance.

Comment: Thanks! I added to ssh-add (which I didn't want to do in the first place - but at least it works) and changed my ssh line which now work much better. Thanks!